# How much of C++11 is usable in Windows Kernel

Tags: windows, c++11, windows-kernel

The latest WDK is delivered to be used with Visual Studio 15, which supports C++11.

However, I have not seen documentation about how much of the functionality is usable.

Obviously, I wouldn't use `std::thread` and `std::mutex`, but less clearly, is the magic statics.

```
Class * function()
{
     static Class myInstance;

     return &myInstance;
}
```

That is now thread-safe in user mode, but it is unclear whether this construction may work in kernel.

More concerning, is pre C++11 code would have been acceptable in kernel (assuming destructor was trivial).

Comment: FWIW, in g++ I saw this implemented with a hidden spinlock, which should probably be safe in kernel mode too.

Comment: A "C with classes" coding style could be made to work.  But sure, traps everywhere you look.  You assumed correct that such a *static* declaration can no longer work, the codegen depends on a TEB and thread-local storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found some documentation about the switch /kernel [msdn : /kernel (Create Kernel Mode Binary)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620896.aspx) which describes a switch to tell the compiler that the .obj is destined for kernel mode.

That describes different behavior for exceptions and RTTI, but fails to mention magic statics.

From a visible decompile of a simple

```
Class * GetInstance()
{
   static Class instance;
   return &instance;
}
```

and some user-mode testing, the compiler

1. Does not emit any thread-local code.
2. Does not provide the thread-safe behavior from usermode.

### edit

For clarity. When `/kernel` was not specified, magic statics worked and static initialization was thread safe. The mechanism (using fs:) was not applicable to kernel.

With `/kernel` the code was NOT thread safe, but was kernel compatible. (No reference to fs:)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are planning to completely rewrite the kernel e deploy a complete new *standardization* of exported names (that means to throw away all the existent executables), I think that would be mostly impossible. Many C++ features are -in fact- *metafunctions* that the compiler have to translate into something existent.

Things like `std::thread` can be implemented as wrappers around a kernel resource (that will be most likely a "pointer to a pointer to a data structure: that's what an HANDLE actually is), by letting those structures to reside into another process and be completely opaque to the *client* programs.

Things like *function calls* to retain such an opacity requires a *standard ABI* (App. Binary interface) all languages can rely on, while producing object code that must be linked.

Now, C ABI -due to the missing of overloading- is trivial (just perpend an `_` to the function name: this is the convention the windows kernel libraries adopt and that every compiler developer have to rely on when making a windows version of it), but C++ name mangling is ... proprietary (there is no definition about how it must be done at system level, so every compiler does its own).

Because of that, the only reliable kernel will be the one the exports only `extern "C"`.
It can be written internally in C++, but it's interface must be plain C in any case (that's just your `class* function();` that's no semantically different from `HANDLE CreateClass()`.

Note that even defining a standard ABI at C++ spec level won't help that much: all C++ compiler will link the same, but no other language will be required to follow.

And system level ABI must be enough simple to don't require to client languages feature (like function overloading) that not all languages are necessarily required to support.

To complicate things even more, C++ also has templates, that instantiate code during compilation and that cannot be reliably implemented across a process boundary or a kernel barrier: imagine the kernel has internally `vector<int>` and `vector<double>`: I can rely on the system whn I have to use those functions, but what about `vecotr<foo>`?

How can I ask the system kernel of all my user to make `vector<foo>` to exist during the compilation of my software on my machine? That can be don during installation, but, again, more standardization of communication interface is required.

A kernel is a manager of physical resources that exist at assembler level. Representing them in C is almost trivial. Representing them in C++ remains trivial if you use the C++ low level features (That are mostly the same as C), but -as soon as you rise up into abstraction- you immediately meet against the missing of standardization and complex non trivial choices about where and how to implement that will translate in to future constrains for things whose usage -at kernel level- may not be so clearly defined.

---

Of course nothing -in principle- prohibits to use C++ internally in the kernel implementation, but that creates problem in boundary management across resource usage.

The actual protocol is "give me access to a resource" and "keep your resource back".

A client program can wrap these two calls in a RAII class and apply all C++11 features on it, but what about moving that on the other side of the boundary?
Can a kernel return a `win::unique<something>`? Well ... not really, since you cannot destroy yourself something that is not inside your process: that "samrt handle" will so have a destructor that result in another call to an kernel function. o the kernel will in any case have a separate Create/Get and Delete/Relese functions.

I can certainly develop an API to your C++ program in term of smart handles, but the program to kernel communication will still be by means of plain functions (hence smart handles are all managed to the client side, anyhow)

Similarly, stack unwinding works if calls are all synchronous, but create/delete are not themselves synchronous (they are not called one inside the other). They are "synchronized" by the RAII pattern, by means of a LOCAL object residing in YOUR stack. But a `*HPEN` (note the dereference) structure is not in your stack: is inside another process (the GDI driver), so a `smart<HPEN>` must call `CreatePen` on construction and `DeletePen` on destruction, since the kernel -by itself- cannot know when your "unwinding" (that's your, not kernel) will come to the right point.

C++ //in kernel// can exist for objects that are entirely constructed and destroyed synchronously by the kernel itself inside a same kernel call, then -by consequence- will not go outside of the kernel, to be somehow used by the client.  This is certainly possible, but since the purpose of a kernel is to export functionality and exporting requires flat APIs, you will soon end-UP with a C++ kernel exporting a plain C interface used by C++ wrapper on the client side.

I doubt the effort is justified.

Comment: Sorry, but this makes very little sense. Operator overloading is resolved by the compiler and invisible at runtime. That means it's invisble to the kernel at runtime as well. Same applies to templates. As for `std::vector<double>`, it's just as safe to pass as `MyType`. At kernel level, you communicate using serialized data in a predefined format.

Comment: This answer focuses on C++ in kernel, rather than C++11 in kernel.  I am aware of the ABI issues, but my question is that the C++xx process seems to add more responsibility to the compiler (safe stack unwinding, thread safe static variable initialization) and there is little evidence that this is coped with in the code compiled for the kernel, and may produce undesirable side effects.

Comment: @MSalters I'm not speaking about the existent kernel, but to an eventually rewritten C++ one.  Overloading of function (not necessarily operator overloading) can be implemented also across DLL boundaries. That where "kernel" make sense. If you stay stick to compilation "local" resolution, you don't move towards a C++ kernel, but stay into C. That's exactly what i tried to demonstrate with this prof by absurd. You came exactly to the my same conclusion.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia: In that kernel, you'd define the C++ ABI, just like todays kernels define their C ABI. Yes, you'd need to say something about stacks, just as todays kernels already have to do - kernel stack don't grow like user-mode stacks do. Furthermore, "overloading across DLL's" is a user-mode runtime concept and thus unrelated to C++, so it's irrelevant o "C++ in kernels" on both counts.

Comment: The addition seems to make little sense either. Besides straying away from the usage of C++ **in** the kernel towards C++ at ABI level, the statement "you can't destroy something that's not in your process" just isn't true. The OS owns the process, and often loads part of itself into each process. (E.g. NTDLL.DLL, to keep to Windows). And that can very well contain `win::unique<HANDLE>::~unique()`.

Comment: A C++ kernel and a C++-based system ABI *can* be done (see BeOS, now Haiku); also maintaining binary compatibility on template types is possible (see Qt, but also `libstdc++` to some degree). But it seems to me that the question was completely different and way more focused on a specific problem (i.e. usage of C++11 inside the code of your specific driver).

Comment: @MSalters: That's what I said.